# Continuity in product topology (Exercise)

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ have the product topology.

Is $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$
$f(t)=(\sin(xt))_{x \in \mathbb{R}}$ continuous?

It looks like:

> $f$ continuous $\Leftrightarrow$ $\forall i \in I\ f_i ∘ f: Y$
> $\rightarrow X_i$ is continuous

Is the Theorem to use here.

(1) In this case $Y=\mathbb{R}, I=\mathbb{R},X_i=\mathbb{R}$ and $f_i$
is the Function $f_{x_0}(t)=\sin(x_0t)$ for a fixed value $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$

The basics in analysis tells us that $f_{x_0}(t)$ is continuous for every $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.
So $f$ is continuous.

Is my calculation correct? Is there something to add?

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The continuity test criterion is indeed

$$f: Y \to \Bbb R^{\Bbb R} \text{ continuous } \iff \forall x \in \Bbb R: \pi_x \circ f \text{ continuous }$$ where $\pi_x: \Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ is the evaluation function $g \to g(x)$ (for any space $Y$)

and indeed taking $Y=\Bbb R$ we see that $\pi_x \circ f$ is just the function that sends $t \in \Bbb R$ to $\sin(xt)$ for some fixed $x$ and this is indeed more than continuous, even differentiable. So we've got a continuous $f$ here, which traces a sort of "path" from the $0$ function to $\sin(x)$ with $t$ from $0$ to $1$, etc.

So your work checks out, IMO.